# Alpha animation in viewDidAppear and viewWillDisappear won't work reliable

Tags: ios, swift

I have a PageViewController which is being added as a subview.

The controller itself works fine, but I'm trying to implement a fade. Therefore I added this to each PageViewController page/view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.alpha = 0
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.15, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 1
    })
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.15, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
        self.view.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

For the **first** view controller inside of the PageViewController, none of the above animations work. For the second - last view controllers only the `viewDidAppear()` animation works.

**How do I get all animations to work for every vc?**

That's how I add the PageViewController to its parent:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if showTutorial == true {
        let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tutorial")
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.frame = view.frame
        view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think because the view controller are added to a page controller, possibly the viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear methods aren't being called like you normally think they would. Put print statements in there to see if they are

If not, I would look into the page controller delegate and whenever you get a callback from that, that a page has changed, run the animations accordingly